# For given integrable function $\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\epsilon x) f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Reading the analysis textbook I found an interesting equation

For integrable function $f$,
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\epsilon x) f(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx\end{align}

I tried to prove this statement from the fact $|\cos(\epsilon x)| \leq 1$ by taking absolute values on the integrands but this only gives the information on $|f|$ not $f$.

Is there any smart way to prove the above equality? [And I simply guess $\sin(\epsilon x)$ have the same equality. How about $e^{-x}$ and other functions?]

Comment: Do you know Dominated ConvergenceTheorem?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, I see! thanks. So I can regard $\cos(\epsilon x) f(x)$ as $f_{\epsilon}(x)$ then Dominated convergence theorem implies above equation